# how to build compile_commands.json for arm project

Tags: arm, language-server-protocol, coc.nvim, clangd

I'm using `coc.nvim/coc-clangd` in vim to read my project source code.

I see that clanged can work if the [compile_commands.json](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html#project-setup) is provided to clanged.

I can compile the project in my ubuntu env with armcc, so I try to use bear to make compile_commands.

But it reported

`ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/${LIB}/bear/libear.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

I can find libear.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bear/. I have no clue why bear cannot work right.

Comment: I add lib path and cc path in bear command: bear -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bear/libear.so --use-cc /opt/arm/ make, it report "ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bear/libear.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored."